# Asp.net click event code appears in aspx page instead of code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, code-behind

When i click on a button to define its click event, it takes me to the  tags of my own aspx page instead of taking me to the code behind/aspx.cs page. This happens for home page only. the other page signup.aspx works fine and does as expected.

This has happened for a number of projects with me in past few months and as i am a beginner, i don't have much idea about this. But yes i have tick marked "**Place code in separate file**" checkbox when creating this website in VS 2010.

Thanks in advance for your help.

### Edit: (Added code)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  %>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head id="Head1" runat="server">
            <title>Employee Login</title>
        <link href="css/Style.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                  <table align="center" class="loginBox">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" CssClass="username"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rqUser" ValidationGroup="loginValidation" ControlToValidate="txtUsername" ErrorMessage="Username"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="password"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rqPass" ValidationGroup="loginValidation" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" ErrorMessage="Password"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="2"><asp:Button ID="btnLogin" Width="60" runat="server" 
                                Text="Login" CssClass="btnLogin" onclick="btnLogin_Click" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><span style="float:left;"><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text="Forgot Password" NavigateUrl="~/forgotpassword.aspx" CssClass="regular_text"></asp:HyperLink></span>
                                        <span style="float:right;"><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" Text="New User" NavigateUrl="~/signup.aspx" CssClass="regular_text"></asp:HyperLink></span>        
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" HeaderText="You must enter following" DisplayMode="BulletList" EnableClientScript="true" ForeColor="White" />
                </table>
            </div>
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>


    Code behind:

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: You can still have code in aspx files within the script tag.

Comment: @BabuJames yes i can have it. In fact that's what happening, code behind appears in script tag on aspx page but while other pages do have their own cs pages, and only home page code behind appearing in the same page could be an issue of VS?

Comment: Did you at some point change the name of your public partial class or the namespace? (in your aspx.cs file)

Comment: So, are you saying that when you double click on a button in design view with VS2010 you are not taken to the code behind with a predefined function to handle the click event of the button?

Comment: @RynoCoetzee no changes made.

Comment: @Dean.DePue - yes exactly this is what happening.

Comment: @MoinShaikh please you share code of Page directive

Comment: At the top of your .aspx page, check if this line '<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="yourapp.default" %>' where the CodeBehind property links is the .CS file (C# code file) and the Inhertis property links to "namespace.partial" class of that .CS file

Comment: @MoinShaikh Is AutoEventWireup="true" in the <%@ Page %> directive at the top of the page? If you want to know what AutoEventWireup is refer to this:msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59t350k3%28vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: dude. Check you page directive.

Comment: @HiralNayak - shared my code. It seems it does not have codebehind reference.

Comment: Thanks @ricky it seems it is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the header of the .aspx file.  There should be a property named CodeBehind which references to your code file. Is something as

```
CodeBehind="yourfile.aspx.cs"
```

If this property is not present, the C# code is placed inside script tags in your aspx. If this property is present, references the cs file with the code behind.  Probably, when you created the file, you did not tick the checkbox "Place code in a separate file" (or similar).

If you want to have the code in a separate folder, you can create a new aspx.cs file with the code (better copy and paste from other file in your solution), and add the property CodeBegind referencing the file.

Answer (score 1):

If its a HTML control, the click event will be define in aspx page by double clicking it. If its an asp control, click event will be defined in code page by double clicking it.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="YourCodePage.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="Default2" %>
```

Comment: it's an asp control - an asp button.

<tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2"><asp:Button ID="btnLogin" Width="60" runat="server" 
                        Text="Login" CssClass="btnLogin" onclick="btnLogin_Click" /></td>
            </tr>

Comment: Ok. Check the top most part of aspx page where you have defined the `CodeFile="YourCodePage.cs"`. Is this the same name as your code behind page?

Comment: thanks for this. the page didnt have codebehind propert at all. that would have caused the issue

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your .aspx page - you'll see a line of code like so (or something similar):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs"
Inherits="yourapp.default"%>
```

The `CodeBehind` property links to the .CS file (C# code file) of the .aspx (asp markup / designer) page

the `Inhertis` property links to "namespace.partial" class of that .CS file

The .CS File should then look something like this:

```
...
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net;

namespace yourapp
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

...
```

If you don't have said properties in your ASPX file - Add them

If you dont have a namespace directive in your C# code behind file - add it 
(Using the name you gave your project of course(check your other files that work how it looks)) and encapsulate everything under namespace (i.e add {} around everyting under the namespace clause)

Comment: Thank you everyone it seems that i somehow missed the codebehind property. Not sure how i missed because other pages of the same site have this property on this home page doesnt have it.

Thanks again

Comment: pleasure - please mark as answered whoever's answer led you to your conclusion