# ASP.Net Button Click Event Handler not auto generated in code-behind, placed in script tags on page instead

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, code-behind

I've been wrestling with this all day.  Opening up an old web application trying to add a method to my page (default.aspx) and have my code behind default.aspx.cs which is referenced in the page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="HoursWorked._Default" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="HoursWorked" %>
```

Some of the symptoms I'm having are intellisense not "seeing" any of the controls from the page, when I double click the button control in the Designer, it creates the following:

```
<script runat="server">

protected void ButtonShowUnderEight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
</script>
```

Code behind starts off as (after all of my using statements):

```
namespace HoursWorked
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Please show us the code for the button.

Comment: `<asp:Button ID="ButtonShowUnderEight" runat="server" Text="Show Under 8 Off" OnClick="ButtonShowUnderEight_Click" />`

Comment: This is all from code on my dev/test server.  My local dev box, where I originally did development, I can open the project up and adding the event handler works properly.  I can double click the button and the auto-wireup works and places it in the code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (VS2013) what helped was based on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24161545/1998025):

1. Remove `CodeBehind="yourfile.aspx.cs"` from the first line of your
   .aspx file which will cause the c# event handler code to be placed into
   your .aspx source file instead.

   ```
   <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="HoursWorked._Default" %>
   ```

   So you are left with:

   ```
   <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="HoursWorked._Default" %>
   ```
2. Now double-click the control in the Designer which should now pop the event handler code inside script tags within your aspx.
3. Next, restore the `CodeBehind="yourfile.aspx.cs"` you had removed in the first step.

   ```
   <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="HoursWorked._Default" %>
   ```
4. Finally, double-click the control which now pops the event handler code inside yourfile.aspx.cs!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="HoursWorked._Default" %>
```

with

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="._Default" %>
```

It does not like when you inherit

`Inherits="HoursWorked.Default"`

P.S, you can also remove

```
<%@ Import Namespace="HoursWorked" %>
```

Comment: I've tried that.  I get "Could not load type: '._Default'."

Comment: @CooperT I got the same error after messing around, apparently adding different projects to a solution does this. Try removing that project and readding it. Should be fixed then

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going back to my original local solution instead of trying to use the ones on my dev and prod servers.  No clue why they were having this issue compared to my original local solution.

Not going to help anyone else having this issue, but instead of investing more time trying to solve this...  I'm sure if I compared everything in my solution folder, something might stick out.

Tim