# Why cannot add any button in existing file of (html) aspx? When adding new button the page will get Server Error in '/' Application (Runtime Error)

Tags: c#, asp.net

The situation is I want to add new button in my html aspx file (existing file). But I keep getting Server Error in '/' Application (Runtime Error) in the page after adding new button. Below is the error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DVDZ.png)

If I remove back the html markup, the page come back OK.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twb6p.png)

```
<asp:button id="btnSelect" runat="server" onclick="select_Click" text="Select"/>
```

Then, I add  inside html markup page , for example below, the Select Button will show a popup message for Selected Date, it's ok like I want. But I cannot add query to save the selected date into SQl database here because the select_Click button event is inside html markup aspx page. It's look like this button is inside Content Control and I'm not allowed to add button inside the existing file of html markup aspx. Then, when I add select_Click event function in my Example.aspx.cs page the button will do nothing. Supposedly the select_Click event function is inside Example.aspx.cs file.

Anyone got any ideas why this happen???
Note: The existing file is created by previous developer.

```
<script runat="server">
    
    protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string targetdate = Request.Form[TargetDate.UniqueID];
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Selected Date: " + targetdate + "');", true);

        
    }
</script>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="container">
        <table id="table2" style="text-align: center; width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1" style="text-align: center; height: 51px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text="Case Detail" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="XX-Large" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Underline="True"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
       </table>
   </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Thankyou for your time by reading this.

Comment: First step is to find out what the actual error is, then add that to your question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first there is "zero" advantage to put the code inside of a script tags with runat=server.

You will get 100% the SAME effect if you just move that code behind.

(and I suggest you do).

However, looking close at your page, we see it is a "child" page. (in other words, you have a master page in effect here).

Remember, ALL THAT using script with runat=server does is inject the code in CODE behind.

but, that means of course you have to place that good old plain jane code stub inside of the content part since that is ALSO where the current page is being injected/placed.

So, really, I would suggest that you DUMP this idea, and there is no advantage I can think of. Why put code in the markup when you WILL AND ALREADY have a code behind page?

Now, all you doing is creating two places to look at code, and worse yet, when  you use ?

All it does is move the code to code behind location anyway!!!

So, your example has to be this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <script runat="server">

        protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string targetdate = Request.Form[TargetDate.UniqueID];
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Selected Date: " + targetdate + "');", true);


        }
    </script>


    <div class="container">
        <table id="table2" style="text-align: center; width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1" style="text-align: center; height: 51px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text="Case Detail" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="XX-Large" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Underline="True"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

In other words, you have to place that code inside of the "content", since that is where all your markup and "code" has to be placed, and that REALLY amounts to just placing that "stuff" into the  "form" tag area on a regular (non master/child page).

However, as I pointed out, really?

Just take that code, cut it out, right click, view->code, and then just paste that code into the code behind. (remove the script tags).

The result will be 100% the same operation.

So, just keep in mind that using "script" with runat="server"?

All it really does is just move that code to the code behind module, and you not find nor see any difference (then if you just had placed that code in the code behind module anyway!).

However, as noted, since you have a master/child page?

Then both markup, and any code for that "child" page?

it has to be placed inside of the content template.

I should also point out in your sample markup? I don't see a button that would run that code stub anyway - so that's missing and that makes even less sense.

So assuming you did add a button inside of that content template?

Then it most certainly could have a click event that runs that button click code stub you have.

So keep in mind the rules that apply to JavaScript code?

They do NOT apply to code behind, and thus the placement rules for script vs script=runat=server does NOT apply in ANY way at all here.

Script tags with runat=server means:

Please move that server side into the code behind code module for that given page. The code running will be 100% the same as if you had placed that server side code directly into the code behind module in the first place. (again: 100% the same result).

So, yes, you should be able to place a button inside of the content template.

like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes I've done like what you said here before by placing the submit_Click event code inside module page (for example: Example.aspx.cs) but the code got Error (Runtime Error) in the html markup page because adding the new button. In other words, when I'm adding any new button in html markup page, will got Runtime Error.

Comment: check an existing page, your setup might need/want to use content2. So, yes, you should be able to drop a button into content area.  flip page into design mode, and now double click on that button - you should now be jumped to code behind. However, it possible that content1 is a page heading or footer - so code would not normally go into that location. You can open up site master to take a quick look, and you see the content page - pick the content page that is inside of the form tags. (it probably has more then one content section).

Comment: see my edit for an example

Comment: Yes, I'm doing as you said and got error. I'm doing in development mode server. In my localhost don't get any problem when adding new button.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing just like you show on your video. Btw, thanks for helping

Comment: ok, then I suggest you create a blank new test page (create that new test page with a master page). Now, open up that test page. Can you add a button? and look "very very" close at the content tags - do they match your broken page?

Comment: Please refer here, I'm having same situation like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787360/asp-net-button-click-event-handler-not-auto-generated-in-code-behind-placed-in

Comment: You have to respond to my troubleshooting questions. does creating a blank new test page (with master) work?

Comment: Link ONLY suggests a workaround in that dropping a button into a page will ALSO inject the script runat-server tags and place that code in the aspx page. However, at the end of the day, the result is the same (copy code from code behind, wrap in script tags as I suggest will work). but, the WHOLE question is why do this? You don't need to unless some really huge good reason exists. In other words, why is the code behind file not being used? And the case here is compounded by the fact of using a master page - which that link was not. Moving server side script tags inside of content will work

Comment: Regarding your question: "You have to respond to my troubleshooting questions. does creating a blank new test page (with master) work?" . Yes, I have tried created new blank page with a master page and adding button and yes I got same error.

Comment: Ok, that is a "big" tell tell sign of some larger issue here.  I mean, this would suggest that most pages are broken, and don't work.  And if most other pages do work (and I assume they are and do work? ). I would look at a existing (working page) that has a master page, and then look at the working page. Which "content" template is/are those working buttons placed into? As I stated, sometimes you find a new blank page (with master) will result in 2 content areas being inserted.   We assume some existing pages work? So, since a blank new page does not work then we have larger problem.

Comment: if you remove that attempted button code in that one page, does a rebuild soltuion work here? I am starting to think this might have been a web site, and your attempting to use + compile this as a web site "application". So, we need to determine if this is a web site, or a web site application.   Something is certainly wrong beyond your posted issues, since as noted, a simple create of blank new web page (with master) does not even work correctly.